# How to send data to server when receiving location update in background mode?

Tags: ios, core-location

**My app is in background,** and then **i receive a location update**. The system **wake up my app for a very short time** that is enough to store the location.

Now i would like also to **send this location to my server**, but i m afraid that the network connection can take longer time (especially if not on wifi) and that the system will move back my app in sleeping state before i reach the end of the connection.

So how can i send the location to my server?

Comment: Use `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`

Comment: hmm, thanks i will take a look on it

Comment: You should definitely see [this chat discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150127/discussion-between-paulw11-and-honey). It's highly related to many questions you asked in the recent days